# Postgresql error when trying to insert Long array

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

`ArrayList temp2 = new ArrayList();`

Im filling this arraylist with longs.

When i am trying to insert this into the postgresql, i use the following:

`UPDATE pb1plnitm SET parents_pb1plnitm_unid = ARRAY[?] WHERE pb1plnitm_unid = ?", temp2, xmlForm.getFieldValueLong("uniqueid"));`

Using JDBC template. But when i try to run this code it gives a error on the "ARRAY[?]". But if temp2 is a single number like: 1253214, it works. Does anyone have an idea?

My error is:

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE pb1plnitm SET parents_pb1plnitm_unid = ARRAY[?] WHERE pb1plnitm_unid = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of [Ljava.lang.Long;. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in error description, make use of `setObject()` method

For Example:

```
Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("text", anyArray);
    pstmt.setArray(1, sqlArray);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You also need to remove the `array[?]` part and only use `SET parents_pb1plnitm_unid = ?`